# Getting new lines in PHP. "\n" wont work in

Tags: php

I have some PHP code that generates some form data and sends it to a .dat file.

I've been googling a lot but can't seem to get it right..

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
$code = $_GET["code"];
$name = $_GET["name"];
$email = $_GET["email"];

$line = $code . ";" . $name . ";" . $email . "\n";

$file = fopen("paameldinger.dat", "a");
fwrite($file, $line);
fclose($file);

echo "Takk du er nå registrert!";
```

Comment: How about `\n\r` ? What are using to view the file?

Comment: Try `"\r\n"` instead of `"\n"`

Comment: what OS is this running under?

Comment: I feel that the OP did not spend enough time researching this.

Comment: I'm running windows

Answer (score 4):

use PHP_EOL instead:

```
$line = $code . ";" . $name . ";" . $email . PHP_EOL;
```